# In the Bohr Model of the atom is the energy level of the electron the same as the wave function and probability function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, orbitals

My guess is someone has asked this in some alternate way and I just failed to find it in the "Questions that may already have your answer" section. I might add that his model "quantizes angular momentum" and I am not sure if these are all equivalent concepts.

Comment: Your question in the title makes no sense. What readings have you made on the topics?

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: Not true. The energy levels are the eigen values of the 'radial' wavefunctions of the H-atom (eigen functions). The physical interpretation of the wavefunction is that its modulus squared is the probability density of detecting the given system (the electron) (in the position basis).

Comment: sorry , I appear to have been led down the wrong path by a lecture on You Tube by Neil Turok ....  I have accepted the answer below  and stand corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The energy level of the electron is a number (with appropriate units of energy), whereas the wavefunction and its associated probability distribution are functions.

As it turns out, the Bohr model got the idea of angular momentum quantization, but the details are largely wrong.  The Bohr model for instance has only one value of angular momentum per energy level, something that is not compatible with experiment.

The solutions of the Schrodinger equation not only predict the correct energies, but also the correct values of angular momentum for each energy level (there is more than one such value in general). It also turns out that, amongst the possible values of angular momentum allowed for a given energy level, the probability distribution for the largest allowed value of angular momentum has a maximum at the radius predicted by the Bohr theory.

Comment: @Sedumjoy This is a reasonable answer.   I might add that I doubt studying the Bohr model will be very helpful to understanding QM, if that's your goal.  While all models are "wrong" on some level, the Bohr model doesn't share the same field description of modern QM, and, as Zero says, does not predict many basic observed features.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't make sense.  Though in general, you shouldn't be trying to look for a one-to-one correspondence with the Bohr model, and actual quantum theory.  **The Bohr model is wrong!**

It was essentially a guess, an attempt at forcing some aspect of quantization into the hydrogen atom, and it was able to be tuned to match a few observations.  But beyond that, it is just a guess, and it is not a good model of reality.  Quantum mechanics is a *different* theory altogether, so you can't look for where the wavefunction is in the Bohr model - there *is* no wavefunction in the Bohr model!